# Can I change the default camera app on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera, defaults, ios

In the latest iOS update (5.1) Apple added the camera to the lock screen, so now I don't need to unlock the phone to take a picture.

Is it possible to change which app is used for this?

I realise that there are potentially privacy concerns around this which the default app nicely resolves by only showing those photos taken in the current session in the camera roll, but regardless, is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no native way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is via a Cydia app called [AnyLockApp.](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/anylockapp-cydia-tweak/) It allows you to configure the behavior of the camera button that appears on the lock screen. You can set any app to be activated by that button. See also the [AnyLockApp page.](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=anylockappDp)

[image: AnylockApp]
Settings screen:
[image: Settings screen]

Edit: As mentioned in the comments and by [stuffe's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/43585/7833), this hack will probably not work in iOS 5.1. However, this is unconfirmed. I will update this answer when I do update and jailbreak iOS 5.1.

Besides this hack, there is no other way to change the behavior of the camera button on the lock screen.

Comment: Btw, he has already updated to 5.1. Will this still work?

Comment: @bassplayer7 I don't know since I haven't upgraded to iOS 5.1. If/when I do, I will update my answer to fit. However, for now, this is the only way.

Comment: Very good point. Makes sense. I just noticed that the website says it doesn't work on iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

Other than jailbreak you are out of luck, the jailbreak version detail in another answer will likely work on 5.0.1 (double tap home to reveal the camera button and volume controls) but in 5.1 it's not a button any more, but a sliding control and as such highly doubtful that a jailbreak hack will be able to modify it's function.

Answer (score 1):

- GrabberApp from BigBoss repo for iOS 5.1
- GrabberApp + CameraGrabber from BigBoss repo for iOS 5.0.1

Comment: Thanks for your answer,can you please explain in details your points?